# Javascript: Parse JSON to Array of Strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, data-structures

I have below JSON defined in the below manner of set, key and value.

```
[{
    "set1": {
        "key1": "value1"
    },
    "set2": {
        "key2": "value2"
    },
    "set3": {
        "key3": "value3"
    },
    "set4": {
        "key4": "value4"
    } 
}]
```

I would like to know how do I use plain/native javascript to get the array of strings in the below manner which consists of only various values.

```
["value1","value2","value3","value4"]
```

I have tried using Object.keys and Object.values but still no luck. It would be helpful to know how to handle it in plain javascript and not use any third party libraries.

Comment: Do you want to remove duplicates or only to display all values?

Comment: this is just to display all values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution:

```js
const data = {
  "set1": {
    "key1": "value1"
  },
  "set2": {
    "key2": "value2"
  },
  "set3": {
    "key3": "value3"
  },
  "set4": {
    "key4": "value4"
  }
}
var result = Object.keys(data).map(_ => Object.values(data[_])[0]);
console.log(result);
```

This outputs
[ 'value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4' ]

Comment: thanks so much, it does work :) but how about if i get the json in a array like [data]

Comment: In your example data is an array with a single entry. If that is the general case, you could use data[0]...
Otherwise, you could iterate over the items of that array.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const data = [{
  "set1": {
    "key1": "value1"
  },
  "set2": {
    "key2": "value2"
  },
  "set3": {
    "key3": "value3"
  },
  "set4": {
    "key4": "value4"
  }
}]

console.log(data.reduce((values, o) => {
  Object.values(o).forEach(v =>
    values.push(...Object.values(v)));
  return values;
}, []));

// Or a more streamined version:

console.log(data.reduce((v, o) => v.concat(
Object.values(o).reduce((v, o) => v.concat(
Object.values(o))
, []))
, []));
```

Answer (score 1):

This will cover the case with multiple array objects.

```js
let data_array = [
    {
    "set1": {
        "key1": "value1"
    },
    "set2": {
        "key2": "value2"
    },
    "set3": {
        "key3": "value3"
    },
    "set4": {
        "key4": "value4"
    } 
    },
  {
    "set5": {
        "key1": "value5"
    },
    "set6": {
        "key2": "value1"
    },
    "set7": {
        "key3": "value2"
    },
    "set8": {
        "key4": "value3"
    } 
    }
];

let result =  data_array.reduce((accumulator, currentValue)=> {
    accumulator.push(...Object.keys(currentValue).map((key) => Object.values(currentValue[key])[0]));
  return accumulator;
}, []);

console.log(result)
```